# How to select rows in which data in a certain column is never repeated-SQL

Tags: mysql

I have a table with just 4 rows.

```
FIRST  LAST    AGE
luke   david   42
jester prince  32
luke   mike    16
sean   paul    22
```

I want to select only those rows in which the first name is never repeated. So the result I need is

```
FIRST  LAST     AGE
jester prince   32
sean   paul     22
```

The sql query should ignore all the rows in which the first name is being repeated. The simple distinct query doesn't work here because it just removes multiple entries. I want a query which can remove ALL the rows of the repeating first name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TRY

```
SELECT * FROM `tbl_name` GROUP BY(`name`) HAVING COUNT(`name`) = 1
```

Comment: I've tried that, it doesn't work. It gives me 3 rows in return. One of those has luke in the first column.

Comment: It's returning all the rows.

Comment: replace "name" by "FIRST"

Comment: It was returning all the rows when I tried it on sqlcourse, but its working fine on sqlfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

You can use group by if distinct does not work

```
   SELECT * FROM Table GROUP BY FIRST
```

Comment: It doesn't remove the names that are repeating.

Answer (score 0):

You may use a `NOT IN` clause, like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table1
WHERE first NOT IN (
  SELECT first FROM table1
  GROUP BY first
  HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
)
```

Inner query finds all first names which are repeated and then using the NOT IN clause those duplicate first names are removed from the final result.

Answer (score 0):

```
select FIRST, LAST, AGE 

from MY_TABLE 

group by FIRST 
HAVING count(FIRST) = 1
```

Comment: Where did count_name come from?