# BigQuery GROUP BY ... HAVING asks for other columns to be grouped

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Running something like this:

```sql
SELECT user_id, username FROM `table` GROUP BY user_id HAVING COUNT(user_id) = 1
```

But BQ console complains that `username` is neither grouped nor aggregated. I'm looking at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27119272/how-to-select-rows-in-which-data-in-a-certain-column-is-never-repeated-sql) post that explains how to remove rows that appears more than once. I'm assuming this error message is because there's no primary key or uniques in BQ? How can I get around this? I just want to eliminate repeated rows by `user_id`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I just want to eliminate repeated rows by user_id.

below should do

```
SELECT user_id, ANY_VALUE(username) as username
FROM `table`
GROUP BY user_id
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want one row per `user_id`, you can just use an aggregation function such as:

```
SELECT user_id, MAX(username) as username
FROM `table`
GROUP BY user_id
HAVING COUNT(user_id) = 1;
```

However, I might suggest using `QUALIFY` instead:

```
select t.*
from table t
where 1=1
qualify count(*) over (partition by user_id) = 1;
```